# Can not minify the css code with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, minify, webpack-4

Webpack version: 4.16.3

All compilation is successful.
My code after compilation in bundle.css is not minify.
I try to use **minimize: true** in text-webpack-plugin, but it not working.

For compile I use command in command line: **webpack** in my working directory

What am I doing wrong?

My wepback config:

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: 'production',
  entry: __dirname + "/js/init.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      noUiSlider: 'nouislider',
      Vue: 'vue'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css")
  ],
  module: {
    'rules': [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        })
      }
      , {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: {
            loader: "css-loader!less-loader",
          }
        })
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|cur)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=imgs/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: what is the version of webpack?

Comment: version = 4.16.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With webpack version above 4  you may like to use [**mini-css-extract-plugin**](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) instead of `ExtractTextPlugin` plugin

Answer (score 17):

Use [OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin) to minify css assets, extractors are used to separate output assets only. Note that minification works with production mode i.e. make sure to pass "--mode production" in the webpack build command.

```
    {....,
        optimization: {
                minimizer: [
                   //Incase you want to uglify/minify js
                    new UglifyJsPlugin({
                        cache: true,
                        parallel: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    }),
                    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
                        cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
                        canPrint: true
                    })
                ]
         }
    ....}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Complete working Webpack 5 example**

Here's a complete example. Not differentiating between production and development, but should be simple to do.

It produces `dist/main.css` which is a minified CSS containing both:

- our `main.scss`
- `normalize.css` via `node_modules`

The effect of both can be seen on the index.html test file.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./main.scss'],
  },
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: [nodeModulesPath],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    minimize: true,
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-cheat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "sass": "rm -f dist/main.css && sass main.scss dist/main.css"
  },
  "author": "Ciro Santilli",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "5.2.4",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "sass": "1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "webpack": "5.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2"
  }
}
```

main.scss

```
@use "normalize.css/normalize.css";

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Sass import</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this plugin instead.

https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin